# Is Homosexuality considered moral because it was seen in 'nature'?

Tags: ethics, argumentation, sexuality

First of all I am not a native English speaker, so please be careful with the heavy vocabulary.

I have been reading some of the arguments which a lot of homosexuality supporters use to support their opinion and one of those and actually considered the strongest is that homosexuality is witnessed among other species. This argument is a counter-example to the claim that homosexuality is not natural, however this argument assumes therefore that any act which is seen in nature is actually moral. This implies, for example, that mating with one's mother, father, sister or daughter should also be considered moral among us. I am sure that anyone here will agree that those kinds of acts are one of the worst acts one can imagine.

This leaves me with two conclusions :

- EITHER the argument is false and can't be used to support
  homosexuality
- OR morals are the only acts which we see in nature, any other acts
  are just a bunch of social conventions.

My question is as listed in the title :

Is Homosexuality considered moral because it was seen in 'nature'?

Comment: It's moral because it involves consenting adults. Otherwise we could outlaw square dancing on the grounds we're not genetically wired for it. The "gay gene" as a moral justification is a terrible argument. It allows the State to outlaw whatever cannot be proved to be genetically determined.

Comment: I am not sure I actually understood what you are saying. As I said before I am not a native speaker and I don't have enough biological backgrounds to understand the scientific terms you use in your comments. Can you please explain in more detail what you are trying to say or at least link me to resources where I can learn what you are saying :)

Comment: A counterexample eliminates an argument, it does not ever make one.  Presuming that a counterexample is *meant* to make an argument, instead of refute one, is the fallacy of arguing from ignorance.  From a traditional theory of rights I do not need to support the morality of homosexuality, *allowing* things does not take effort, *preventing them* requires action.  If your argument for preventing something falls apart, you need a new argument, not a distortion of my refutation into a classical fallacy.

Comment: Many believers consider homosexuality to be immoral on religious grounds, and in some cases rely on "unnaturality" to infer God's disapproval. Animal homosexuality refutes this line of reasoning, but it is not in itself an argument for morality of anything. "x is natural" does not imply "x is moral" any more than "x is unnatural" implies that "x is immoral". Morality is not derivable from nature, on the majority view that would be the ["naturalistic fallacy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is%E2%80%93ought_problem). Those who accept homosexuality as moral also hardly base it on what animals do.

Answer (score 3):

[Male lions eat the cubs of other lions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infanticide_(zoology)) to maximize the chances of their own offspring thriving. This is natural behavior, yet no one will ever argue that it is moral behavior.

Arguments against the morality of homosexuality are purely religious. If you don't accept the religious argument against homosexuality, then there is really no way of arguing against it. In particular, any argument against homosexuality as somehow being harmful would have to apply to any non-reproductive sex act between consenting adults, and I'm pretty sure nobody wants to go there.

Comment: *"Male lions eat the cubs of other lions to maximize the chances of their own offspring thriving. This is natural behavior, yet no one will ever argue that it is moral behavior."* – isn't this just repeating what the OP said himself?

Comment: *"If you don't accept the religious argument against homosexuality, then there is really no way of arguing against it."* – Why? Explanation? See the 2nd half of my answer. If you accept all the premises there and the further premise that frustrating the purpose of a part of our bodies is immoral, you'll probably get there. No religion involved. Okay a nonreligious person who follows medieval Scholastic natural law theory to its bitter end would be a very strange creature. ;-) Also not all ethical systems are about harm. Think about Kant's "lying to the axe murderer".

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats as I mentioned in my answer, because such reasoning would apply to any non-reproductive sex act, or to any will abstinence from reproduction.

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. Non-reproductive sex acts would be frustrating the purpose and be immoral (and you can be nonreligious and believe that, too!). I wonder why a lot of intelligent people in the past, like Marx, who weren't religious at all, were still homophobic. So I'm not playing the devil's advocate, it's more about understanding them.

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats I think that the non-religious homophobes of the past were just carrying over baggage from Judeo-Christian-Islamic culture that they grew up in.

Comment: I know that's the usual explanation. But isn't it strange how long it takes even for an explicitly anti-religious culture to reverse this course? Homosexuality was recriminalized by the Soviet government in 1933 and only became legal after the fall of the USSR in the Russian Federation in 1993.

Comment: Why did Napoleon "get it" instead? Hey, even Sultan Abdülmecid I., who decriminalized homosexuality in 1858 in the Ottoman empire, "got it".

Comment: @AlexanderSKing  Hate to argue against my own issues, but it is hard to blame JudeoChristian culture for a long tradition of homophobia in rural China and the traditionally polygamous parts of Africa.  I think it is about wanting the best return on investment out of every child in a harsh environment -- if  maintaining the family farm absolutely demands grandchildren, gay relationships are frowned upon.  If clearing land calls for tons of poor, disenfranchised males to compete for a limited number of women, letting them pair off is unwise.

Comment: @jobermark don't know about Africa and China. I always assumed it was Judeo-Christian-Islamic because the Greeks seemed to be fine with it until they became Christian. That and the notorious Bible and Quran passages.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing  Again, not so much.  Plato himself authored a set of city laws where he had to bow to pressure to outlaw homosexuality.

Comment: @jobermark wasn't perderasty supposed to be a social institution among the ancient Greeks, also my namesake was supposedly gay and that didn't seem to be a problem for them? Not questioning your facts, just trying to understand.

Comment: Tibetan Buddhism is also pretty homophobic. So people came up with this "idea" independently from each other.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing it was a social institution, but still some, like Aristotle, found it unnatural: _"others are morbid states resulting from custom, e.g. the habit of plucking out the hair or of gnawing the nails, or even coals or earth, and in addition to these paederasty; for these arise in some by nature and in others, as in those who have been the victims of lust from childhood, from habit."_ (from the NE)

Comment: @AlexanderSKing  Beyond that, pederasty is one thing, but permanent relationships between adult males were a different story entirely.  They suggest positive regard for an adult male passive partner, and they might logically lead to someone not reproducing.

Comment: They seem to have been approved of in prosperous military cultures (like Athens, Macedonia and Sparta) and denigrated in poor agricultural ones.  But our information comes mainly from the former, so we get a skewed view.

Comment: I really think the link to extremely inefficient agriculture is more telling than religion.  (Not that deciding what to teach your children so that you can more efficiently use them as economic resources is moral by modern standards either.)

Comment: Given how interconnected almost all Old-world cultures are, I wonder if there are any records of Native American attitudes towards Gay people? That might server as a useful tool for understanding homophobia.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing in pre-columbian America it ranges from accepting and totally cool with it to extremely hostile, something punishable by death (like in the case of the Aztecs – female homosexuality included).

Answer (score 2):

First, you overestimate the agreement that incest is morally wrong. Yes, I would find it viscerally disgusting to “mate” with my sister, but many philosophers wouldn't accept this subjective feeling as an argument for the claim that incest between adult siblings is morally wrong (if it is consensual and no children are conceived).

Now to the main point: There are people who argue that because homosexuality is not found in nature (which is incorrect), it must be immoral. In this case the argument that it *is* found in nature shows a fatal flaw in the premise of this reasoning.

Of course, this alone does not mean that homosexuality (or more precisely, a homosexual act) is moral, it just refutes the argument before it even starts. You would need to supply *another* argument to justify your claim that homosexuality is immoral. Because in general, the person making the claim has the burden of proof.

In reality, something else is behind the meaning of “natural”, which is not found in the clumsy and wrong argument that homosexuality is not found in nature. It means that by looking at the genitals we can guess what their purpose must be – presumably heterosexual intercourse.

So the argument would be: Since a homosexual act frustrates the purpose of the genitals, it is immoral.

But this line of reasoning assumes *a lot.* Arguing on the basis of purposes (teleology) is not fashionable anymore. That's something from the Scholastics in the middle ages. It would be rejected by most philosophers today.

And even if we agree (contra Darwin) that there are purposes in nature and in ourselves, can we really be so sure that we can correctly detect those?

And even if we accept that homosexuality frustrates the purpose of the genitals, it still doesn't follow that homosexuality is immoral. Because why should the frustration of the purpose of something be morally wrong?

Comment: I like how you describe incest as something we don't do because we find that disgusting instead of something we don't do for a reason. But isn't moral a really subjective anyway ?

Comment: Incest also removes traditional spaces of safety from sexual pursuit in the home.  Removing a barrier that others rely upon because you are an exception still has its own implicit moral problems.  It would be impossible to establish consent without already breaking the taboo that protects sexual innocence between those forced to live together for reasons that are not their own choice.  For the same reason that propositioning a subordinate is already wrong, even if they consent.

Comment: @jobermark The argument about incest is usually predicated as only applying to situations wherein there isn't an unfair power dynamic in play. For example, an adult brother and sister who are living on their own but decide to become romantically involved is completely different than a father having a relationship with his much younger daughter who lives at home. As you said, the latter case is similar to workplace power abuse. But this argument is usually invoked in situations when that is *not* the case. Most everyone agrees that taking advantage of a power dynamic is immoral.

Comment: @Winter if morality is purely subjective (I didn't write anything about this because the whole question makes only sense if we believe there is something objective about morality), we would still have two different subjective categories for “feels disgusting” and “is immoral”.

Comment: @Not_Here  Even establishing consent in such situations requires breaking a taboo that has a purpose.  I did not mean there was necessarily a power imbalance in incest, but that the taboo against leveraging the power imbalance is parallel to the taboo that protects safe space.  Many people need to have some place where sex is just off the table.  Traditionally that is the nuclear family.  And you cannot find out who those people are until you have already threatened them.

Comment: @jobermark I personally would see a potential for harming oneself psychologically if one has consensual sex with one's adult sibling. Aside from the disgust factor, I also very much would want such a relationship to stay innocent. Someone so close to you and you bring sex into the mix doesn't sound like a good idea. Agreed. But probably BASE jumping is not a good idea, too! Yet from this it doesn't follow that BASE jumping is immoral. And why does society have the right to unilaterally declare something as a safe space? What if society declares same-sex interactions as a safe space?

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats I think that is a real component of some historical objections.  But to me it is silly.  It is kind of insane to want the same set of relationships that society leverages when they want people to kill one another to be kept sexually safe.  If you might be ordered to just take me out if our elders disagree, there are not a lot of things the two of us can be too mutually protective about..

Comment: Thank for your answer :l, I think it opened my mind to a lot of new ideas about morality. I think I need to give it enough thought before answering the arguments you listed , even though I already have some answers. It is correct that I mistakenly overestimated the argument but thats because I spoke with a lot of people who use it as an argument not counter example. I think every issue on morality will bring us back to the most fundamental questions "What is good and what is bad ? Is morality subjective or objective?".